# ERROR 1292 (22007) in mysql for INSERT INTO SELECT CURRENT_DATE()

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to keep daily count of rows in table `MASTER_TABLE` older than a particular date in table `OLD_COUNT` using sql query:-

```
INSERT INTO test_db.OLD_COUNT(Count, Date) SELECT COUNT(*),  CURRENT_DATE() FROM test_db.MASTER_TABLE WHERE TIMESTAMP(UPDATE_DATE) < '2015-11-12 15:36:20';
```

Executing this, gives me an error `ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2015-11-12 19:20:15:850'`

**My issue is insert query failing at** `WHERE TIMESTAMP(UPDATE_DATE)`

Executing `SELECT COUNT(*),  CURRENT_DATE() FROM test_db.MASTER_TABLE WHERE TIMESTAMP(UPDATE_DATE) < '2015-11-12 15:36:20';` gives me expected output

```
+----------+----------------+
| COUNT(*) | CURRENT_DATE() |
+----------+----------------+
|        0 | 2015-11-18     |
+----------+----------------+
1 row in set, 11 warnings (0.04 sec)
```

`OLD_COUNT` has columns `Count` as `bigint(20)` and `Date` as `date`.
`MASTER_TABLE` has column `UPDATE_DATE` as `varchar(30)` ( example of relevant data is `2015-11-12 19:20:15:850` ). *Unfortunately I cant change the table definition or force any program to enter data in any pre-defined format. Hence I have to make-do with any relevant data I can find*.
I am using 5.6.26 MySQL

Could anyone please shed some light on why `INSERT` query is failing while `SELECT` works or what is wrong with my query?

**--------UPDATE--------**
Pardon me if

> ( example of relevant data is 2015-11-12 19:20:15:850 ). Unfortunately I cant change the table definition or force any program to enter data in any pre-defined format. Hence I have to make-do with any relevant data I can find

did not communicate my contraints correctly.

I only need to consider data which may be converted to `TIMESTAMP` automatically in accordance to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp). Data such as `Wed Nov 10 19:25:27 PST 2015` or `1447934215` ( others formats which I have no control over ) are **not relevant but are present**.
`UPDATE_DATE < '2015-11-12 15:36:20'` or any derivative of the same compare them lexicographically not chronologically( as `UPDATE TIME` is `varchar(30)`). It works now appreciably on my test bed but on production data (such as as `10-11-2015 7:25:27 PM`) may be present.

Comment: Do you have a trigger on OLD_COUNT table which might be the cause of the error?

Comment: @Adish , no we have not configured a trigger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Difference in behaviour between `SELECT` and `INSERT` statement arises with `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` sql mode being enabled by default on MySQL.
`SELECT` statement executes but with warnings ( such as `Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2015-11-12 19:20:15:850'` ).
When same `SELECT` statement is incorporated in the `INSERT` statement, in `Strict SQL Mode` these warnings are treated as errors and data insertion is aborted.

> If strict mode is not in effect, MySQL inserts adjusted values for invalid or missing values and produces warnings (see Section 13.7.5.41, “SHOW WARNINGS Syntax”). In strict mode, you can produce this behaviour by using INSERT IGNORE or UPDATE IGNORE.
>
> For statements such as SELECT that do not change data, invalid values generate a warning in strict mode, not an error.

**Using** `INSERT IGNORE` **resolves the issue**. One may also use `SET SESSION sql_mode = '';`

Specifically for MySQL version 5.6 docs can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html), but a better read may be [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#ignore-strict-comparison)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
WHERE UPDATE_DATE < '2015-11-12 15:36:20'
```

instead of

```
WHERE TIMESTAMP(UPDATE_DATE) < '2015-11-12 15:36:20'
```

Edit:

If the part you need is always in the same position and timestamp() gives you errors you can try

```
Substring(UPDATE_DATE, position, length)
```

For options of substring you can look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)

Edit2:

To get data in comparable formats you can try

```
STR_TO_DATE(UPDATE_DATE, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

(select the best format for your needs) then apply substring like this:

```
Substring(STR_TO_DATE(UPDATE_DATE, '%Y-%m-%d'), position, length)
```

Comment: That would work if data format was specifically restricted to `%Y-%m-%d %T`. But here table has ( _non-relevant_ )  data such as `Wed Nov 10 19:25:27 PST 2015` among which I needn't consider.

Comment: I tried them, it still fails for above stated `Wed Nov 10 19:25:27 PST 2015`, All I really want is my `insert` to work like`select`

Comment: @parthasarathy wich you tryed?

Comment: @genepos
I tried `mysql> INSERT INTO test_db.OLD_COUNT SELECT COUNT(*),  CURRENT_DATE() FROM test_db.MASTER_TABLE WHERE TIMESTAMP(SUBSTRING(UPDATE_DATE FROM 1 FOR 19)) < '2015-11-12 15:36:20';` gives me `ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: 'Wed Nov 10 19:25:27'`

Comment: @parthasarathy  `SUBSTRING('Wed Nov 10 19:25:27 PST 2015' FROM 1 FOR 19) ` returns 'Wed Nov 10 19:25:27'. Are you sure it's what you need?

Comment: @genepos
I have updated question to answer your query

Comment: @parthasarathy I've added some hints